# Check if there is a real linear mapping with properties $L: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I had a similar question before but this time I want make sure if I did it correctly myself on this example:

> Check if there is a real linear mapping with properties $L:
> \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{3}$
>
> $L\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  2 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\  0\\  0
> \end{pmatrix}, \text{ }\text{ }L\begin{pmatrix} 2\\  1
> \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  1\\  0 \end{pmatrix}, \text{
> }\text{ }L\begin{pmatrix}
> -1\\  4 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\  0\\  1 \end{pmatrix}$
>
> If there exists such linear mapping, write its matrix form.

Let the matrix of the linear mapping $L$ be $M= \begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix}$

So for the first thing we have $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
d & e & f\\ 
g & h & i
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$

and we already see that there is no linear mapping because the matrices have invalid size so we cannot even multiply them.

Is it correct like that?

Comment: Remember that matrix of linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ has $n$ columns and $m$ rows.

Comment: $L$ is a linear mapping from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$. That means that a matrix that represents $L$ (such as $M$) shouldn't be $3\times3$, but rather...? That being said, I think finding a matrix representation is unnecessary in this problem. Just use the fact that your three vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ are linearly dependent and that $L$ is linear to check.

Comment: @Arthur $2 \times 3$ ?

Comment: Almost. Swap them over.

Comment: @Arthur Alright thank you :) By the way, would I harm myself if I deleted this question (I heard you can be banned for doing it)?

Comment: No, not really. At least not formally. However, if someone is currently typing an answer for you, they will be interrupted and their half-finished answer disappear. That has happened to me, and it's mildly annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{bmatrix} -1\\4\end{bmatrix} = 3\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

If L were a linear map then $L\left(3\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix}-2\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\end{bmatrix}\right) = 3L\begin{bmatrix} 1\\2\end{bmatrix} - 2L\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\end{bmatrix}$

But it doesn't, so it is not.